# DNS Resolving failure in Windows but works in other OS

Tags: windows, networking, dns, nslookup

(Caution: The website is in Chinese)

I am trying to access a website (http://zp.sesedu.cn).

I **cannot** access it using any Windows computer, including

- two Windows 10 computers (one Windows 10 home and one Windows 10 Pro)
- Windows 10 running in VMware (host OS: Windows 10)
- Windows XP running in VMware (host OS: Windows 10)
- wsl in Windows 10
- wsl2 in Windows 10

I **can** access it using:

- Ubuntu 20.04 running in VMware (host OS: Windows 10)
- iPhone
- iPad
- macbook

All devices are testing in the same private LAN network (I tried to let a computer to use my phone's cellular network via hotspot. The result is the same. Phone can access the website under cellular networks, but the computer cannot via hotspot).

In Windows 10 computer,

- http://www.sesedu.cn (ok)
- http://zp.sesedu.cn (dns not found)
- ping [www.sesedu.cn](http://www.sesedu.cn) (ok)
- ping zp.sesedu.cn (Ping request could not find host zp.sesedu.cn. Please check the name and try again.)
- nslookup -d -q=A zp.sesedu.cn

```
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0`

    QUESTIONS:
        1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN

------------
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        zp.sesedu.cn, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  zp.sesedu.cn
        canonical name = 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
        ttl = 600 (10 mins)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
        ttl = 10 (10 secs)
        primary name server = ns1.cyudun.net
        responsible mail addr = mail.cyudun.net
        serial  = 2
        refresh = 600 (10 mins)
        retry   = 180 (3 mins)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 180 (3 mins)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        zp.sesedu.cn, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  zp.sesedu.cn
        canonical name = 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
        ttl = 600 (10 mins)
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
        ttl = 10 (10 secs)
        primary name server = ns1.cyudun.net
        responsible mail addr = mail.cyudun.net
        serial  = 2
        refresh = 600 (10 mins)
        retry   = 180 (3 mins)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 180 (3 mins)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    zp.sesedu.cn
```

- wsl2 (nslookup with set debug)

```
Server:         172.18.64.1
Address:        172.18.64.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
        zp.sesedu.cn, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  zp.sesedu.cn
        canonical name = 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn.
        ttl = 0
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
zp.sesedu.cn    canonical name = 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn.
------------
    QUESTIONS:
        6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
        origin = .
        mail addr = mail.jiasule.net
        serial = 1
        refresh = 600
        retry = 180
        expire = 1209600
        minimum = 180
        ttl = 31
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
```

- Ubuntu in VMWare (nslookup with set debug)

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    zp.sesedu.cn, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  zp.sesedu.cn
    canonical name = 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn.
    ttl = 5
    ->  6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
    internet address = 203.156.232.54
    ttl = 5
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
zp.sesedu.cn    canonical name = 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn.
Name:   6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
Address: 203.156.232.54
------------
    QUESTIONS:
    6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
```

- wsl2 (dig zp.sesedu.cn)

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> zp.sesedu.cn
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20985
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zp.sesedu.cn.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
zp.sesedu.cn.           0       IN      CNAME   6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.18.64.1#53(172.18.64.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 28 07:02:35 CST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 88
```

- Ubuntu in VMWare (dig zp.sesedu.cn)

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> sesedu.cn
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59813
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sesedu.cn.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sesedu.cn.      5   IN  A   203.156.232.54

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 27 15:18:07 PDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

- wsl2 (Winshark capture)

```
11  33.336171   fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 92  Standard query 0xa51e A zp.sesedu.cn
12  33.343446   fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 191 Standard query response 0xa51e A zp.sesedu.cn CNAME 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA ns1.cyudun.net
13  33.345605   fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 112 Standard query 0x39cb AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
14  34.357758   192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x39cb AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
15  35.360638   fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 112 Standard query 0x39cb AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
16  35.394420   fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 163 Standard query response 0x39cb AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
17  35.394420   192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 143 Standard query response 0x39cb AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
18  35.394964   fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 163 Standard query response 0x39cb AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
19  35.395023   fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 112 Standard query 0xdf18 AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
20  35.395136   192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 92  Standard query 0xdf18 AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
21  37.423682   192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 143 Standard query response 0xdf18 AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
22  37.423881   fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 163 Standard query response 0xdf18 AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
```

- Ubuntu in VMWare (winshark capture)

```
1   0.000000    192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 72  Standard query 0x6093 A zp.sesedu.cn
2   0.008763    192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 171 Standard query response 0x6093 A zp.sesedu.cn CNAME 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA ns1.cyudun.net
3   0.010332    192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x72da A 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
4   2.011939    192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x72da A 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
5   2.042496    192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 108 Standard query response 0x72da A 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn A 203.156.232.54
6   2.042496    192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 108 Standard query response 0x72da A 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn A 203.156.232.54
7   2.047382    192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x9a9a AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
8   4.049005    192.168.3.26    192.168.3.1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x9a9a AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn
9   4.083906    192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 143 Standard query response 0x9a9a AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
10  4.083906    192.168.3.1 192.168.3.26    DNS 143 Standard query response 0x9a9a AAAA 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA <Root>
```

- Windows 10 powershell (nslookup with Winshark capture)

```
1   0.000000    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 152 Standard query 0x0001 PTR 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa
2   0.002857    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 152 Standard query response 0x0001 Server failure PTR 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa
3   0.005092    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x0002 A zp.sesedu.cn
4   0.020710    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 191 Standard query response 0x0002 A zp.sesedu.cn CNAME 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA ns1.cyudun.net
5   0.024557    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x0003 AAAA zp.sesedu.cn
6   0.031796    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 191 Standard query response 0x0003 AAAA zp.sesedu.cn CNAME 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA ns1.cyudun.net
7   0.032143    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x0004 A zp.sesedu.cn
8   0.035289    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 191 Standard query response 0x0004 A zp.sesedu.cn CNAME 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA ns1.cyudun.net
9   0.035939    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 92  Standard query 0x0005 AAAA zp.sesedu.cn
10  0.038326    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 191 Standard query response 0x0005 AAAA zp.sesedu.cn CNAME 6e4dc53dbfcdc5ee.cname.365cyd.cn SOA ns1.cyudun.net
```

- Windows 10 powershell nslookup [www.sesedu.cn](http://www.sesedu.cn)

```
1   0.000000    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 152 Standard query 0x0001 PTR 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa
2   0.002493    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 152 Standard query response 0x0001 Server failure PTR 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.e.f.ip6.arpa
3   0.004864    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 93  Standard query 0x0002 A www.sesedu.cn
4   0.006959    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 109 Standard query response 0x0002 A www.sesedu.cn A 203.156.232.54
5   0.010536    fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   fe80::1 DNS 93  Standard query 0x0003 AAAA www.sesedu.cn
6   2.034102    fe80::1 fe80::e150:5276:2d4e:7a9b   DNS 163 Standard query response 0x0003 AAAA www.sesedu.cn SOA vip1.alidns.com
```

I can see the difference using Winshark is that Windows & wsl2 in Windows uses IPv6 and somehow it doesn't recursively query the DNS, but I still do not know the reason yet.

Could it be the problem of my router or remote DNS server (for example, don't support IPv6)?

I hope someone can give me some hints on what happened.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `nslookup -d -q=A <domain>` on Windows to see details of the received response. Run a packet capture using Wireshark; see if there's something weird in the DNS response packets, and if they're different between Windows and Ubuntu/macOS. Don't forget to try alternative DNS servers using `nslookup <domain> <server>`.

Comment: @user1686 thanks. I tried winshark and updated the results.